# Separate geom_tile by blank space

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dfataframe (`df1`) that looks like so:

```
   x y           z
1  a 1 -0.13031299
2  b 1  0.71407346
3  c 1 -0.15669153
4  d 1  0.39894708
5  a 2  0.64465669
6  b 2 -1.18694632
7  c 2 -0.25720456
8  d 2  1.34927378
9  a 3 -1.03584455
10 b 3  0.14840876
11 c 3  0.50119220
12 d 3  0.51168810
13 a 4 -0.94795328
14 b 4  0.08610489
15 c 4  1.55144239
16 d 4  0.20220334
```

Here is the data as `dput()` and my code:

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"
), class = "factor"), y = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), z = c(-0.130312994048691, 0.714073455094197, 
-0.156691533710652, 0.39894708481517, 0.644656691110372, -1.18694632145378, 
-0.257204564112021, 1.34927378214664, -1.03584454605617, 0.148408762003154, 
0.501192202628166, 0.511688097742773, -0.947953281835912, 0.0861048893885463, 
1.55144239199118, 0.20220333664676)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))

library(ggplot2)  
p1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y))
p1 <- p1 + geom_tile(aes(fill = z), colour = "grey20")
p1 <- p1 + scale_fill_gradient2(low = "darkgreen", 
                                mid = "white", 
                                high = "darkred",
                                breaks = c(min(df1$z), max(df1$z)),
                                labels = c("Low", "High"))
p1
```

With this code (inspired from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42641106/add-a-second-geom-tile-layer-in-ggplot)) I get this figure:

[image]

Now I wondered whether soemeone has an idea to separate some columns (here isolate a, b, and cd) to get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved using faceting like so:

1. Add a new faceting variable
2. Use `facet_grid` with arguments `space="free"` and `scales="free_x"`
3. Remove the facet strip text via `theme()`

```r
library(ggplot2)
df1$facet <- ifelse(df1$x %in% c("c", "d"), "cd", df1$x)

p1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y))
p1 <- p1 + geom_tile(aes(fill = z), colour = "grey20")
p1 <- p1 + scale_fill_gradient2(
  low = "darkgreen",
  mid = "white",
  high = "darkred",
  breaks = c(min(df1$z), max(df1$z)),
  labels = c("Low", "High")
)
p1 + facet_grid(.~facet, space = "free", scales = "free_x") +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]